# Getting the ID of an object when the object is given

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have link that calls a function when clicked:

```
<a href="javascript:spawnMenu(this);" id="link1">Test1</a>
```

To make my function work, I need access to the object so that I can perform jQuery operations like this:

```
alert($(objCaller).offset().left);
```

Since `objCaller` points to the object and not the object ID, this won't work. I need something like this:

```
alert($("a#link1").offset().left);
```

How can I get the object ID from `objCaller`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="spawnMenu(this);" id="link1">Test1</a>
```

You can't pass `this` via a javascript: url.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this work?

```
objCaller.id
```

Comment: `<a href="javascript:alert(this.id);" id="link1">Test1</a>` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's because you can't pass `this` in an href. Pass it via the `onclick` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head: does `alert($(this).offset().left);` not work? Otherwise, you can get the ID via `$(this).attr("id")`.

Comment: See Rob's answer below. I didn't even look at that part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what objCaller refers to. If it refers to the element itself, then $(objCaller) would work fine with jQuery.

Try your code using firebug (an extension for firefox). You can swap 'alert' for 'console.log' so you have:

```
console.log(objCaller);
```

This will help you work out exactly what is stored in objCaller (it isn't an element if $(objCaller) isn't working, as I say).

If objCaller is an element, then objCaller.id would be the way to retrieve the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID by doing this:

```
function spawnMenu (elem) {
    var id = elem.id; // elem is just a DOM node, so access it's id

    // your code here...
}
```

However, jQuery should also be able to wrap a DOM node, so the following should work as well:

```
function spawnMenu (elem) {
    elem = $(elem).get(0);

    // your code here...
}
```